# how to reduce memory usage in image gd or speed up the process to deallocate memory faster

Tags: php, gd, memory-management

I have an image GD script which is currently using around 9MB of memory.
I get a lot of traffic and hence sometimes it using up hell lot of RAM on my server.

Is there any way to reduce memory usage for image gd?
Or at-least make script process faster so that it de-allocates the memory which it is using, faster.

I have tried changing image quality, it had no effect.
I also tried changing image pixel size, it reduced the memory usage, but not much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell without seeing the code, but unless it contains any major mistakes, then the answer is probably no.

What you might be able to do is use the external [`imagemagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org) binary instead - it runs outside PHP's script memory limit - but that is an entirely different technology, and would require you to rewrite your code.

I assume you are already caching GD's results so not every request causes it to run?

Comment: There is a lot of code to be shown but i will try to explain you what i am doing with code. I have an image file, and i have about 10 other small thumbnail images and about 40 other strings, which are to be put up on that image file. I think caching might not help as new image is generated everytime as thumbnail images/strings keep changing everytime. Any help?

Comment: @Anil hmm, that sounds indeed difficult to cache. Apart from some memory optimizations that *might* be possible (like unsetting variables right after you don't need them any more etc.) I don't think there is much potential for optimization

Comment: i have already unsetting vars. Do you think there can be a way for image GD to process faster? so that the script gets completed faster and deallocates the memory to make room for other requests.

Comment: @Anil Except for buying a faster server, I don't think so, no.

Comment: looks like i need to move my web application to a cloud server, probably. Traffic spikes are eating my whole RAM sometimes. Thanks for help though :)

Comment: https://github.com/francodacosta/phmagick is a wrapper around the suggested imagemagick so you don't need to learn command line parameters to resize images. Just use PHP API.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding using image GD on the fly if you are concerned about memory limits. 
It's hard to solve the problem without seeing code, but i can make a suggestion.

Have a different process handle the images, for example, if you want to resize images, don't resize them everytime the user access a page, instead run a cron or a scheduler with window to  resize all the images that needs to be resized periodically and save them. so there will be less overhead.

If you provide more code you will get better help

Comment: There is a lot of code to be shown but i will try to explain you what i am doing with code. I have an image file, and i have about 10 other small thumbnail images and about 40 other strings, which are to be put up on that image file. Each time thumbnails/strings are different. I also cannot use cron as i have to show output image to the end user instantly.

Comment: sounds like you are using these images for captcha, how big are the images in pixels when you render? maybe making smaller images can help

Comment: @lbu, no, its not captcha but something similar. Yes, reducing image size helped reduce a memory usage, but not much. Sadly, reducing image size is not an option for me in my web application.